# Pine script giving error: Incorrect 'for' statement. Expecting 'to <expression>'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
indicator("Stock Price Above 200 SMA and 10 Period RSI Below 30", shorttitle="Stock Price and RSI Indicator")

// Define inputs
sma_period = input(title="SMA Period", type=input.integer, defval=200, minval=1, maxval=1000)
rsi_period = input(title="RSI Period", type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1, maxval=100)

// Define calculations
sma = sma(close, sma_period)
rsi = rsi(close, rsi_period)
above_sma = close > sma
below_rsi = rsi < 30

// Count occurrences of conditions between Feb 2017 and Feb 2023
occurrences = 0
for i = 0 to bar_index do
    in_range = (time >= timestamp("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z")) and (time <= timestamp("2023-02-01T23:59:59Z"))
    if in_range and above_sma[i] and below_rsi[i]
        occurrences := occurrences + 1

// Output result
plot(occurrences, title="Occurrences", color=color.green)
```

When I am running the above script, there is an error message saying

> Incorrect 'for' statement. Expecting 'to <expression>'.

I expected to get the number of occurrences when RSI < 30 and SMA > 200 for a stock in the form of a line on the chart of the stock, but instead I am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple errors in your script. The syntax for the inputs was wrong, the sma and rsi's were missing the ta. namespace and you had the word 'do' after bar_index in your for loop. Try this version. Plotted for me no issues

```
//@version=5
indicator("Stock Price Above 200 SMA and 10 Period RSI Below 30", shorttitle="Stock Price and RSI Indicator")

// Define inputs
sma_period = input.int(title="SMA Period", defval=200, minval=1, maxval=1000)
rsi_period = input.int(title="RSI Period", defval=10, minval=1, maxval=100)

// Define calculations
sma = ta.sma(close, sma_period)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, rsi_period)
above_sma = close > sma
below_rsi = rsi < 30

// Count occurrences of conditions between Feb 2017 and Feb 2023
occurrences = 0
for i = 0 to bar_index 
    in_range = (time >= timestamp("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z")) and (time <= timestamp("2023-02-01T23:59:59Z"))
    if in_range and above_sma[i] and below_rsi[i]
        occurrences := occurrences + 1

// Output result
plot(occurrences, title="Occurrences", color=color.green)
```